# Calling class constructor with parameter - request of a member in 'x' which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, gcc, most-vexing-parse

I have a class A that accepts class B as a constructor parameter. Class B can be constructed from int value. My original code is quite complex, but I hope I've reduced it to the very base case:

```
class B {
public:
    explicit B(int a) : val(a) {}
private:
    int val;
};

class A {
public:
    A(const B & val) : value(val) {};
    void print() {
        //does nothing
    }

private:
    B value;
};


int main() {
    int someTimeVar = 22;
    A a(B(someTimeVar));
    a.print();
}
```

And this is the error code I'm getting:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -Wall -O0
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:22:7: error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘A(B)’
     a.print();
       ^
test.cpp:20:9: warning: unused variable ‘someTimeVar’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int someTimeVar = 22;
         ^
```

I use GCC (4.9.2 20150304 (prerelease)), platform: arch linux.

The following modification to the main function compiles fine:

```
int main() {
    A a(B(22));
    a.print();
}
```

I'm well aware that using A a(); declares a function, not a object. But I didn't expect that A a(B(some_val)) will do the same, and in my opinion this is what's happening here.

Do you have ideas why this is happening?

---

Edit: Thank you for all the answers, looks like I need to research more on most vexing parse idea.

BTW it turns out that compiling my code using clang provides more useful error message plus a solution:

```
$ clang test.cpp 
test.cpp:21:8: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    A a(B(someTimeVar));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:21:9: note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable
    A a(B(someTimeVar));
        ^
        (             )
test.cpp:22:6: error: member reference base type 'A (B)' is not a structure or union
    a.print();
    ~^~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Comment: Well, your opinion is a fact. `a` is a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem has its own tag here on stackoverflow. most-vexing-parse

Wikipedia har a clear description of the problem and its solution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.

> The line
>
> ```
> TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());
> ```
>
> could be disambiguated either as
>
> - a variable definition for variable time_keeper of class TimeKeeper, passed an anonymous instance of class Timer or
> - a function declaration for a function time_keeper which returns an object of type TimeKeeper and has a single (unnamed) parameter which
>     is a function returning type Timer (and taking no input). (See
>     Function object#In C and C++)
>
> Most programmers expect the first, but the C++ standard requires it to
>   be interpreted as the second.

The solution is to add parenthesis to the argument like:

```
     A a( (B(22)) );
```

or as others have noted use universal initialization like

```
     A a { B{22} };
```

Comment: _Most programmers expect the first, but the C++ standard requires it to be interpreted as the second._ - For me this is really counter-intuitive - can someone explain the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @kamilm the rule is that if it is syntactically valid as a declaration then it is treated as a declaration.

Answer (score 7):

`A a(B(someTimeVar))` is interpreted as `A a(B someTimeVar)`, so `a` is a function taking parameter of type `B` and returning `A`.

This is one of the reasons the uniform initialization was added to C++11:

```
A a{B{someTimeVar}};
```

Answer (score 2):

`A a(B(someTimeVar));` declares a function with the return type A and one argument of type B named someTimeVar. It's the same as `A a(B someTimeVar);`

It works in `A a(B(22));` because 22 is not a valid identifier, so the functio declaration would be invalid.

If your codebase uses C++11 (or newer), you can use uniform initialization with curly braces: `A a(B{someTimeVar});`